# startForeground Notification does not show Title or Content

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I'm starting a foreground service which uses a HandlerThread to do some long running tasks.

**It works fine, however, the notification does not show my title or content (It says "xxx is running " Tap for more information or to stop the app"). I'm targeting Android 10 for now**

The service is started from my main activity

```
Log.w(TAG, "startServiceCalled")
Intent(this, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
    startForegroundService(intent)
}
```

In the `onCreate` callback of the Service I'm putting the service in the foreground like this

```
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
    Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
}

val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, MainActivity.RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL.id)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setContentTitle("My Custom App")
    .setContentText("MyService Ready")
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .build()

startForeground(NOTIFICATIION_ID, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MANIFEST);
```

BTW: I'm also using Flutter so my main activity extends FlutterActivity

EDIT: The notification channel is created like this

```
val RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL = NotificationChannel("com.example.notification", "Service notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT).apply {
    description = "Provides information about the service"
}
val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL);
```

Comment: You need to create notification channels above Android O. See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did. See Edit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the issue:

You need to set a valid small icon. Otherwise the notification display will fail silently during startForeground.

```
val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, MainActivity.RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL.id)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("MyService")
        .setContentText("Recording Service Ready")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()
```

I discovered this when trying to display the notification manually using NotificationManager.notify.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is valid.

You need to add
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />` to your AndroidManifest.xml
to visualize app alarm on your device.
(even if there's no such thing as SecurityException.)

And then turn your app alarm on.